# React native VS Flutter which is better

Tags: react-native, flutter, cross-platform, mobile-development

I'm new in cross-platform mobile development, I wanted to know which is better between React Native and Flutter.

Also, what is the best resource for the best one between them?

Answer (score 4):

Flutter is far better then React Native in terms of preformance.
Sometimes react Native doesn't work the same  in both platform.
Google  investing a lot in flutter and also React Native can produce only android and ios apps.
But same flutter code produces android , ios , web , windows desktop apps, macos desktop apps, and cherry on the top Google will introduce fuchsia Os which is far better than android and only flutter will be the language to create fuchsia apps.

Best sources for flutter are 
its own liberary
udemy courses can help
flutter has its own channel that's very helpful.